# (Batch) How To send the `@Echo Off` function from one .bat file to another

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am able to send most of my code from one `.bat` file to another by surrounding the entire thing in parenthesis.

```
(
@echo off
Echo Example
Pause
Cls
Echo Example
Pause 
Cls
)>>Random.bat
```

However This Does not send the `@echo off` function

I Tried Doing it Separately but then only the `@echo off` would send.

```
Echo @Echo Off >> Random.bat

(
Echo Example
Pause
Cls
Echo Example
Pause 
Cls
)>>Random.bat
```

I Need a way to send all of it at once.

Comment: What happend if you add the `@echo off` as the first line *inside* the parenthesis?

Comment: Why did you delete your previous question that I answered for you?

Comment: Your code does not copy the command-sequence to the file.

Comment: Adding The `@echo off` within the parenthesis does not send it either. I Even tried to put a delay between the `@echo off` and the the parenthesis. I Used the command `TIMEOUT /T 1 > NUL`

Answer (score 2):

If you are seeking to write commands into the `Random.bat` file, you might try something like this.

```
(
    ECHO @Echo Off
    ECHO Echo Example
    ECHO Pause
    ECHO Cls
    ECHO Echo Example
    ECHO Pause
    ECHO Cls
)>>Random.bat
```

Comment: Adding `Echo @Echo Off` to the top of the list (under the open parenthesis) if you want the resulting batch file to `@Echo off` in it.